# Applying a Legend to an Image using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am making an anatomy learning module for students.

I cannot conceptualize how to solve this problem.  I am trying to make a live/dynamic anatomy label system.  Such that if the student clicks certain input type checkboxes then certain groups of anatomy labels will appear.

I have a mockup here:

http://www.textbookofradiology.com/anat.php

depending on which group if checked the image changes to highlight the relevant antatomy, in essence showing the legend of each anatomic structure.

Can someone tell me if this is possible to create using PHP/HTML and Jquery?  If so how?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is definitely possible. However, you would need a plugin to actually edit the images in very specific ways. Even tho I said it is possible, it is also extremely tough to do. I myself wouldn't want to have a go at it.

I do have a different solution for you, however.

With photoshop you can create layered picures. (you have to color the areas in with a program anyway, right?)

**option 1:**
Use a plugin to read out layered photoshop files and trigger layers on and off depending on the checkboxes

or, my personal favorite and the easiest way to do this, **option 2:**
Create layers in photoshop, each with one of those colors colored in. (thus, not harming the original)
Now only take those colored areas (Hide the other layers in photoshop) and save them as .PNG of .GIF files (anything with a transparent background)

Once you're done doing this and have all the colored (equally sized!) image files, you simply use jQuery to fade them in and out.

You will display 4 pictures over eachother.

```
   <!-- create a new wrap for every part -->
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="imgcontainer upperbody">  
        <img src="http://www.textbookofradiology.com/images/anat/chestanatomy.jpg" class="original" alt="" />
        <img src="http://www.textbookofradiology.com/images/anat/chestanatomyred.jpg" class="first overlay" alt="" />
        <img src="http://www.textbookofradiology.com/images/anat/chestanatomypurple.jpg" class="second overlay" alt="" />
        <img src="http://www.textbookofradiology.com/images/anat/chestanatomyyellow.jpg" class="third overlay" alt="" />
    </div>  
<!--checkboxes here with classes "1", "2" and "3"-->
    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" class="firstCB"/>red<p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="secondCB"/>purple<p>
    <input type="checkbox" class="thirdCB"/>yellow<p>
</form>
</div>
```

You will have to position the images absolute with css like this:

```
   .imgcontainer{
    position:relative;
    height:600px;
}
.imgcontainer img{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
}

.imgcontainer img.original{
  z-index:1;
}
```

Now, whenever a checkbox is checked you will use jQuery to fade in the overlaying pictures.

so you start off like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //hide pictures
    $('.overlay').hide();
    //on the first checkbox click
    $('.firstCB').on("click", function() {

        //if it was checked
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            console.log("red");
        $(this).parents(".wrap").find('.first').fadeIn();
        }
        //if it was unchecked
        else {
            $(this).parents(".wrap").find('.first').fadeOut();
        }
    });
        $('.secondCB').on("click", function() {

        //if it was checked
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            console.log("purple");
            $(this).parents(".wrap").find('.second').fadeIn();
        }
        //if it was unchecked
        else {
            $(this).parents(".wrap").find('.second').fadeOut();
        }
    });
        $('.thirdCB').on("click", function() {

        //if it was checked
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            console.log("yellow");
       $(this).parents(".wrap").find('.third').fadeIn();
        }
        //if it was unchecked
        else {
            $(this).parents(".wrap").find('.third').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

The javascript should work for all new images and checkboxes as long as you keep the classes the same. But don't forget to copy-paste this on-click trigger and change it to the second and third classes.

As for the HTML, just rinse and repeat with the same classes.

Comment: thanks.  But the form checkboxes don't display....  JS Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/S8yk5/

Comment: This is my first time working with jsfiddle so I hope I did this right. I forgot a few dots (class selectors) and made a new, safer way to do this. It works now.

http://jsfiddle.net/S8yk5/2/

P.s. the images do overlay, but don't forget that you should save the text only, without a background for it to work together. Now the background of each new image will overlay the previous one.